# Dynamically populate a custom form in Woocommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, product

I have the following code that puts a basic hidden form on my woocommerce product page with a button (it is part of a plugin that I am trying to write that adds some custom options entered in the backend. `myplugin_option_name` is one of these strings.)

I basically want this form populated dynamically based on the current product details and the method I've tried to use below (from what I've manage to pickup/learn) just doesn't work and I'm not sure how to proceed. I've tried various other methods of dynamically populating fields based on other solutions to other questions but none of them worked in my instance.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
    global $product;

    $url_part = get_option('myplugin_option_name');
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $url = home_url;

    echo '<form action="https://example.com/transactions" method="POST">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="locationId" value="{$id}" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="workflow" value="{$url_part}" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="callbackUrl" value="{$url}" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" value= "Customise Product"></input>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Maybe it is something fairly simple that I'm missing because I've had very little sleep in the last few days trying to teach my self php in order to get this working, so I apologize in advance if it is a minor (stupid) error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your code… try the following instead *(untested, without any guarantees)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 35 );
function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
    global $product;

    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $home_url   = home_url(); // <== a mistake here
    $option_url = get_option('myplugin_option_name');

    // Display form and populated fields
    echo '<form action="https://example.com/api/transactions" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="locationId" value="'.$product_id.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="workflow" value="'.$option_url.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="callbackUrl" value="'.$home_url.'" />
    <input type="submit" value= "'.__("Customize Product", "woocommerce").'"></input>
    </form>';
}
```

It should better works now.